# Understanding how apps in roles are served in Azure

Tags: azure, azure-web-roles, azure-worker-roles

The company I work for is looking to develop a few apps against the cloud.

- An ASP.NET Web Api application hosted in an Azure web role.
- A Windows Server type application hosted in an Azure worker role.

We are completely new to web or cloud development and would like to know the following:

When being served to the consumer, is the same instance of the application being served to all, is it one per request or are multiple roles being created and served to consumers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When being served to the consumer, is the same instance of the application being served to all?

That depends on how many instances you've asked Azure to run your application on. If you've only deployed to 1 instance, then it will of course be the same instance that responds to all requests. But if you deploy to multiple instances, requests will be load-balanced, which means you have no guarantee that multiple requests from the same user will be handled by the same instance.

When you're asking this question, it could be because you might be tempted to store local data on the machine running the instance. However, this is not a good idea. Windows Azure can at any time tear down your instance and start your application on a completely different machine. They call this "healing", because it usually happens because Windows Azure tries to be helpful and avoid any potential problem that could mean downtime for your instance. But it also happens if your machine for some reason locks up or something else bad happens. This process of healing means that anything that's not part of your deployment package will be lost. So for example, if you're logging to a file on the disk, this log will be lost if Azure "heals" your instance.

> is it one per request or are multiple roles being created and served to consumers?

I'm not completely sure what you mean here, so I'll take a guess and risk interpreting your question wrongly. My guess is that you're asking if there will be one instance per user request. No, there will only be the number of instances that you have decided. Remember that you have to pay per instance that's running, so it's only fair that the number of instances running is dictated by you.

When you have your application packaged and ready to be deployed to Windows Azure, you can decide how many instances of each role you want to have running. You set this number in the deployment package, so that when your package is deployed, Azure will automatically start the requested number of instances. However, you can change the number of running instances of each role after deployment and on-the-fly. This makes it possible for you to scale with more instances within minutes.

I hope this helps and that I understood your questions correctly. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Azure Web and Worker roles in an Azure Cloud Service are deployed on at least one instance (managed VM).  Azure allows you to size (memory, CPU) and scale (number of instances).  Azure actually lets you scale dynamically, i.e. add more instances on demand.  You pay by the hour for the size & number of instances deployed.

For example, a Cloud service can have a single instance of a worker role (background processing) and multiple instances of the Web role.  Multiple instances are handled behind a load balancer and the client is unaware of what instance they are using (all instances are created equal).

Answer (score 0):

An Azure role instance is a VM with some specific payload.

For example, in your service you declare you want three instances of "Frontend" web role and two instances of "Backend" worker role. When Azure deploys your service it starts five VMs and three of them will run "Frontend" payload and have IIS started and two of them will run "Backend" payload and have no IIS started.

Now until you ask Azure to change that configuration it remains persistent no matter what requests come and what load occurs. You have five VMs with 3+2 configurations. To change the configuration you need some action on your part.

There're two way to have the configuration changed. You can use Management Portal or an external program to change the "instance count" in either or both roles. You can also add auto-scaling code that will gather metrics and make Management API requests to alter the "instance count". Either way when "instance count" goes up Azure starts more VMs with the same payload and when it goes down it stops some of the VMs.